# how can i easily convert the json to such ArrayList Of custom type?

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, gson

I have a json string which i want to convert to `ArrayList<Offer>`

I have tried to use gson and got this error:

`offersList =  gson.fromJson(res, ArrayList<Offer>);`

`Syntax error on token ">", Expression expected after this token`

how can i easily convert the json to such ArrayList Of custom type?

**update**

I have tried @weston answer and it worked paritally

for this json, i got the foolowing array:

```
[ { "address" : "my street 22, my city, my country",
    "endDateTime" : "2014-03-25T17:10:07.1466Z",
    "id" : "d8ffd4e6-6166-4fb5-bc88-10a7639bbdae",
    "latitude" : 32.457799999999999,
    "longitude" : 34.457799999999999,
    "media" : [ "0fe424fe-70cc-46fe-b" ],
    "recurringType" : 1,
    "startDateTime" : "2014-03-25T19:10:07.1466Z",
    "target" : 0,
    "title" : "some campaign title bla bla"
  },
  { "address" : "my street 22, my city, my country",
    "endDateTime" : "2014-03-25T17:10:01.749Z",
    "id" : "a860cd99-df4d-449d-b19b-9be8e65d30b1",
    "latitude" : 32.457799999999999,
    "longitude" : 34.457799999999999,
    "media" : [ "e859818f-6dbc-4801-9" ],
    "recurringType" : 1,
    "startDateTime" : "2014-03-25T19:10:01.749Z",
    "target" : 0,
    "title" : "some campaign title bla bla"
  },
  { "address" : "my street 22, my city, my country",
    "endDateTime" : "2014-03-25T17:09:57.0222Z",
    "id" : "7578c31d-477b-47c8-bf29-9f7ac39d8520",
    "latitude" : 32.457799999999999,
    "longitude" : 34.457799999999999,
    "media" : [ "a08bb80e-9522-4bb3-b" ],
    "recurringType" : 1,
    "startDateTime" : "2014-03-25T19:09:57.0222Z",
    "target" : 0,
    "title" : "some campaign title bla bla"
  },
  { "address" : "my street 22, my city, my country",
    "endDateTime" : "2014-03-25T17:09:52.1394Z",
    "id" : "47471ea4-c3d5-466f-993f-050cfe6aaa0a",
    "latitude" : 32.457799999999999,
    "longitude" : 34.457799999999999,
    "media" : [ "ac7ad715-bbb0-4649-b" ],
    "recurringType" : 1,
    "startDateTime" : "2014-03-25T19:09:52.1394Z",
    "target" : 0,
    "title" : "some campaign title bla bla"
  },
  { "address" : "my street 22, my city, my country",
    "endDateTime" : "2014-03-25T17:09:47.0226Z",
    "id" : "eceaa9ec-5cfa-4eb9-bf98-fec55d632977",
    "latitude" : 32.457799999999999,
    "longitude" : 34.457799999999999,
    "media" : [ "61c37b9d-7feb-4384-9" ],
    "recurringType" : 1,
    "startDateTime" : "2014-03-25T19:09:47.0226Z",
    "target" : 0,
    "title" : "some campaign title bla bla"
  },
  { "address" : "my street 22, my city, my country",
    "endDateTime" : "2014-03-25T17:09:41.9682Z",
    "id" : "8157b0fc-48d1-472e-9961-664a627c7676",
    "latitude" : 32.457799999999999,
    "longitude" : 34.457799999999999,
    "media" : [ "ae4fc57a-a5c4-49b7-a" ],
    "recurringType" : 1,
    "startDateTime" : "2014-03-25T19:09:41.9682Z",
    "target" : 0,
    "title" : "some campaign title bla bla"
  },
  { "address" : "my street 22, my city, my country",
    "endDateTime" : "2014-03-25T17:09:33.5286Z",
    "id" : "179299a4-97a3-4721-8e9c-ff744cb1d9a0",
    "latitude" : 32.457799999999999,
    "longitude" : 34.457799999999999,
    "media" : [ "0d74f51b-427c-4e9f-8" ],
    "recurringType" : 1,
    "startDateTime" : "2014-03-25T19:09:33.5286Z",
    "target" : 0,
    "title" : "some campaign title bla bla"
  },
  { "address" : "my street 22, my city, my country",
    "endDateTime" : "2014-03-25T17:09:28.5834Z",
    "id" : "eb23d519-a153-41ed-88d9-2ec095d77397",
    "latitude" : 32.457799999999999,
    "longitude" : 34.457799999999999,
    "media" : [ "844c1735-fe68-4d15-8" ],
    "recurringType" : 1,
    "startDateTime" : "2014-03-25T19:09:28.5834Z",
    "target" : 0,
    "title" : "some campaign title bla bla"
  },
  { "address" : "my street 22, my city, my country",
    "endDateTime" : "2014-03-25T17:09:23.8098Z",
    "id" : "03ab9a80-75cf-4b5a-8a61-d1a403105aa3",
    "latitude" : 32.457799999999999,
    "longitude" : 34.457799999999999,
    "media" : [ "a8f91f37-0181-4d95-b" ],
    "recurringType" : 1,
    "startDateTime" : "2014-03-25T19:09:23.8098Z",
    "target" : 0,
    "title" : "some campaign title bla bla"
  },
  { "address" : "my street 22, my city, my country",
    "endDateTime" : "2014-03-25T17:09:18.3186Z",
    "id" : "64bb8624-94fe-4314-8ba4-abeed832140a",
    "latitude" : 32.457799999999999,
    "longitude" : 34.457799999999999,
    "media" : [ "e34f51ff-9f70-4721-9" ],
    "recurringType" : 1,
    "startDateTime" : "2014-03-25T19:09:18.3186Z",
    "target" : 0,
    "title" : "some campaign title bla bla"
  }
]
```

[image]

I understand why all fields are null, but 
why are the two **items** last ones null?

Comment: Parse out the JSON string and create a new `Offer` object as you loop through

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to put `.class`

```
offersList =  gson.fromJson(res, ArrayList<Offer>.class);
```

Which would work for non-generic types, but for collections you need to do:

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Offer>>(){}.getType();
offersList = gson.fromJson(res, collectionType);
```

According to https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples

Comment: In my experience the second suggestion is the actual solution

Comment: please see my updated question. why are the two last ones null?

Comment: @EladBenda the underlying array in an `ArrayList` is often larger than the `size`, which is `10`, which is correct. This is so that you can add to the list without it resizing this underlying array so often. So indexes `[10]` and `[11]` are invalid and you couldn't access them with a call to `offersList.get(10)` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you don't want to use Google's library, you can use Apache's library which comes with Android API. Use http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html (JSONArray) and http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html (JSONObject)

(Please make edits to this, I don't know how to add links ;))

Comment: ` which comes with Android API` can you please give an example? that's not so clear to me

Comment: Please see my new answer to see how to use `JSONArray` and `JSONObject`

Comment: At some point you should learn how to use links! So why not now? Just do this: [text here](link here)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this code

```
String strJSON = ......;
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(strJSON);
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject job = arr.getJSONObject(i);
    //use job.getString() job.getInt(), etc to retrieve data and add to adapter
}
```

You can find more info on `job.getString()` and `job.getInt()` from the links I gave in my earlier answer

Comment: Why didn't you add this to your other answer?